# How to reduce disk usage on a live usb 12.04 system?

Tags: live-usb, disk

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, the live usb version.

Soon virtual disk on live usb gets full, after `apt-get update`.

`df -h /` shows:

```
Filesystem  Size    Used Avail    Use%    Mounted on 
/cow        124M    124M     0    100%    /
```

How can I reduce disk usage on this live system?

Answer (score 1):

The startup disk creator allows you to make a USB drive with any amount of space you want allocated to the home filesystem.  If you intend running Ubuntu regularly from a USB stick then burn the image to a fair sized stick and allow as much as you want to be used by Ubuntu.  If you are using it that regularly, you might want to consider a hard-drive installation?